# Looping over rows of data frame while passing multiple parameters to a user defined function

Tags: r

I have two data frames: 1) df_events 2) df_payments. Both contains user_id's and timestamps, while payments table also stores payment amounts. A new column revenue needs to be added to the events table that would be a sum of amounts for a particular user up until the time of an event.

Here's my attempt at accomplishing that. Consider this as a pseudo-code:

```
 getRevenue <- function(userid,event_time) {

      temp <- filter(df_payments, user_id == userid & payment_time <= event_time)
      revenue  <- sum(temp$amount)
      return(revenue)

 }

 for (row in 1:nrow(df_events)) {

      df_events[row,"revenue"] <- getRevenue( df_events[row,"user_id"] , df_events[row,"event_time"] )

 }
```

Been reading up on apply family but what throws me off is the need to look up two parameters simultaneously and do different things with them. Usually apply examples demonstrate the use of a single parameter such as FUN=function(x) myfun(x) but how do I pass two columns from the row and treat these columns differently, i.e. perform == comparison with one and <= with the other?

Comment: See `?mapply`. The "m" is for "multivariate". Though joining your two data frames together and using data table or dplyr might be more straightforward.

Comment: You're much more likely to get useful code in answers if you make a small reproducible example. Either simulate or share a small subset of your data.

Comment: Thanks, Gregor! Went ahead and joined the tables, problem solved.